# Do enemy animal companions give XP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, animal-companions, experience-points

So I'm creating an enemy level 9 druid NPC for my Pathfinder game I DM.

The enemy has a bear as an animal companion and I want to know **if I should reward XP for killing the bear, in addition to the XP from the druid.**

So this is supposed to be a CR8 (druid level 9). But does the enhanced bear add challenge to the CR level and XP gain?

I already know that creatures summoned from *Convoct Monsters XX* do not provide XP, but does a companion?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Animal companions are just considered to be part of the class features of that enemy. Same reasoning applies to why you don't gain XP by defeating summons from a spell caster if the spell caster gets away.

Comment: To be fair you should be getting exp if the enemy runs away, "Characters advance in level by **defeating monsters, overcoming challenges, and completing adventures**" not having to kill everyone.

Comment: @williamporter My experience is if they run away they will only return to try and attack us again. You need to deal with them which normally means kill, but other methods do exist.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering as the bear had more HP than the druid itself, but it makes sense the druid is weak as its companion is used as a tank buffer while he casts spells.